# Connecting to a private network using a server with public IP

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have a computer (I'll call it *server*) that has a public IP that I can access through ssh from everywhere with an internet connection (tested). This same computer has another ethernet connection that connects to a private (192.168.....) network (I can ssh the *server* and then ssh another computer on the 192.168.... network). I want to be able to have a computer (I will call it *client*) connected to the internet that can interact with the second network of the *server* as if the *client* was connected to that network (i.e. like if the *client* had an IP 192.168... on the *server* secondary network).

Is VPN an option for this problem? I have followed this [OpenVPN](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial without success, when I connect the *client* to the *server* with the VPN network, the client can ping the *server* 192.168... card but does not have internet or cannot ping/see any other computer on the 192.168... network. Any idea on how can I give the *client* acess to the 192.168... network?

Comment: WireGuard is easier than OpenVPN. Also check [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle)

Comment: What do you mean "without success"? What is the step you are stuck in the tutorial?

Comment: I've rephrased the question to clarify my problem.